# Unity 8 not working

Tags: unity

[image][image: this is the screen shot]

Every time i try to start unity 8 in Ubuntu 16.10.
It does not start.
I have to restart then i get this bug report.

Comment: What hardware do you have (GPU/CPU)? Note: Unity 8 is *not consumer-ready*, and nor is it a stable Desktop Environment. The support we can provide here in AskUbuntu will be limited.

Comment: hardware config - 4 GB ram, Intel bay graphics , 500gb hard disk, quad core intel pentium 5 th gen

Comment: What errors are listed in /var/crash/<unity8crashfile>, or ~/.xsession-errors?

Comment: screenshot is the most details it provides  me. I don't know how to open the report

Comment: Use the command "cd" to navigate to /var/crash. Use "ls" to list files, and use "nano" or "gedit" to view the crash logs. Do the same with the directory ~/.xession-errors.

Comment: i add one more screen shot. but all these files are either empty or not showing me any result i tried opening it with su also but nothing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48158/discussion-between-japsimran-and-patrick-negus).

Answer (score -1):

It's quite a common bug, Unity 8 is still in development and really unstable and missing tons of features, it's just a demo, not all PCs support it. In the next updates it will be made better and will support a wider range of PCs. There is not much help we can give.

Comment: unity did start up 2-3 times in the beginning when i newly installed 16.10

Comment: It is not a demo; as it ships with a supported Ubuntu release, we should attempt to help the user best as possible.